# How can I display ordering using drf_yasg

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

How to deal with ordering in drf_yasg?

I have a View:

```
class ContentView(ModelViewSet):
    ....
    ordering_fields = ['price',]
```

But when I open swagger I cant see this possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe somebody need this too.

I use [django_filters](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) package and in this case we should use `filter_class` on our view and there we can define ordering as we need.

Example:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters, OrderingFilter

from contents.models import Content


class ContentFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    order = OrderingFilter(
        # tuple-mapping retains order
        fields=(
            ('price', 'price'),
        ),

        field_labels={
            'price': 'Content price',
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['price']


# my view in views.py

class ContentView(ModelViewSet):
        filter_class = ContentFilter
        .....
```

Now you can use ordering `?order=price` or `?order=-price` and you can see it on swagger docs
[image]

More info about OrderingFilter in django_filters [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
        
class OrderingFilterWithSchema(OrderingFilter):
            def get_schema_fields(self, view):
                self.ordering_description = [enter image description here][1]ordering choicese: " +  ', '.join(view.ordering_fields)
                return super().get_schema_fields(view)
```

And in your view:

```
class ListView(ListAPIView):
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilterWithSchema]
    ordering_fields = ['price', 'created_at', 'manufacturer_year', 'spent_kilometers']
```

And the URL will be like:

```
?ordering=-price  or ordering=price
```

...etc